# How can I display a clickable playlist in my object-oriented HTML5 JS audio player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, playlist

I have an operational audio player built in HTML5 and Javascript (with some basic CSS) but I'd like to add a clickable playlist, so the name of the audio track being played is displayed and songs can be clicked on and immediately start playing.

Here's my JS:

```
function Jukebox() {
  this.playlist = ['song1.mp3', 'song2.mp3', 'song3.mp3', 'song4.mp3']
  this.currentIndex = 0
  this.audio = $('#audioPlayer')[0]
  this.audio.src = this.playlist[this.currentIndex]

  // console.log(this.audio)

  this.play = function(){
      this.audio.play();
      // console.log(this.currentIndex)
  }

  this.pause = function(){
      this.audio.pause();
  }

  this.stop = function(){
      this.audio.pause();
      this.audio.currentTime = 0;
  }

  this.next = function(){
      this.audio.pause();
      this.currentIndex++;
      if(this.currentIndex == this.playlist.length){
        this.currentIndex = 0
      };
      this.audio.src = this.playlist[this.currentIndex];
      this.play();
  }

  this.prev = function(){
      this.audio.pause();
      this.currentIndex--;
      if(this.currentIndex <= 0){
        this.currentIndex = this.playlist.length - 1
      };
      this.audio.src = this.playlist[this.currentIndex];
      this.play();
  }

}

var thisIsMyJukebox = new Jukebox()


//pass the play function by reference
$('#playBtn').click(function(){
  thisIsMyJukebox.play()
})
$('#pauseBtn').click(function(){
  thisIsMyJukebox.pause()
})
$('#stopBtn').click(function(){
  thisIsMyJukebox.stop()
})
$('#prevBtn').click(function(){
  thisIsMyJukebox.prev()
})
$('#nextBtn').click(function(){
  thisIsMyJukebox.next()
})

});
```

The audio files are on my hard drive and the songs have proper names that I could write in, they're just named this way in the code folder because it's shorter.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: nvm, i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Boostrap, you can just add all the songs as a button list. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-buttons

Comment: Thank you for responding; I've never used Bootstrap successfully and this project was already kind of difficult for me (I'm a beginning programmer), I'm not sure this is the best time to start...